# Filling jButtons with icons

Tags: java, swing

So I'd like to fill in 50 buttons with icons, the way I tried doing this was:

```
String table1[][] = new String [5][10];
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
        table1[i][j] = "W";
    }
}
String table2[][] = new String [5][10];
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
        if(i<1){
            table2[i][j] = "jButton"+j;
        }else{
            table2[i][j] = "jButton"+i+""+j;
        }
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
        if(table2[i][j].equals("B")) table2[i][j].setIcon.. /* code 2 set icon 2 long
    }
}
```

So I filled in a second table with jButton names and then tried calling it like: table2[i][j].setIcon, what is the correct way of going about this?

Answer (score 4):

You are using arrays of String and then call setIcon on a String...

Replace your String array with a JButton array.